# Unable to use GLFW3 with python on Mac

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew, glfw

I was trying to use glfw with python on Mac with arm architecture (M1 Silicon) Big Sur 11.2.3

The following error keeps coming out.

```
import glfw                         # lean window system wrapper for OpenGL
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/glfw/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
raise ImportError("Failed to load GLFW3 shared library.")
```

GLFW **has been installed** with `brew install glfw` and the python wrapper with `pip3 install glfw`. I also tried to force re-link it with `brew link glfw --force`

I also tried to build glfw from source and install with it macPorts but no success.

Comment: `brew install glfw3` ?

Comment: As stated, already done.

Comment: Do `brew install glfw` and `brew install glfw3` install the same libraries?

Comment: yes its the same libraries...

Answer (score 1):

According to docs, https://github.com/FlorianRhiem/pyGLFW#macos - set the `PYGLFW_LIBRARY` to your glfw library.

This is what worked for me - `export PYGLFW_LIBRARY=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glfw/3.3.8/lib/libglfw.dylib`